# Getting a Zend_Db_Table resultset to return different types of objects

Tags: php, oop, zend-framework

Let's say I have a `DbTable_Product` table class that represents a table `product`. When I query that table i.e.

```
$myProducts = $productTable->fetchAll();
```

I get a resultset of `DbTableRow_Product` objects. This is fine and it's the way I've done it forever.

I've just now come up against a problem for a second time in two projects, in which I want to be more specific with the object types returned in the resultset.

For instance, let's say almost all of the products don't have any special behaviour, so using the generic `DbTableRow_Product` class is suitable for them. But there is one difficult product that does need additional behavior.

Say there's a class I've created called `DbTableRow_Product_Phone` that inherits from `DbTableRow_Product`. I want the table object to return `DbTableRow_Product` objects when the resulting row is not a phone, and `DbTableRow_Product_Phone` when it is, all in the same resultset.

I've done this in a previous project by overriding the `fetchRow`, `fetchAll`, `getRowClass` and `createRow` methods in the table object to create the correct type of object. This works but it seems dirty.

Is there an easier way of creating different object types in a `resultset`, depending on the type of row? Does this approach even make sense?

Comment: Sounds to me like _either_ your code is not well structured, but (more likely) your tables aren't well designed/layed out...

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Thanks, and it's possible. I guess this is for the rare instances where my rows do everything I need them to, but there's a couple of difficult ones that want a bit of extra behavior. I don't think these "special" products need their own table though. The code structure is pretty much standard Zend Framework as well (as far as I can tell - not doing anything funky).

Comment: Sounds to me like something I used in Doctrine. They called it inheritance http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine1/en/latest/en/manual/inheritance.html

Comment: @MikeB Thanks Mike, I'll take a look at that. Looks pretty close to what I'm trying to do